# Trying to clear form when submit button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clear my form when the submit button is clicked. It opens a page in a new window, and the value typed in the input field is still showing.

```
function clearform (formid){
$('#'+formid).reset()
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form id="email-subscribe" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=MYURI&amp;loc=en_US" method="post" target="_blank">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" tabindex="1" placeholder="Enter your email" />
        <button type="submit" onClick="clearform('email-subscribe');" >Submit</button>
        </form>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @j08691 I don't think it's a duplicate of that. See the comments to my answer -- he wants to clear the form and submit it at the same time, which is more complicated.

Comment: @Barmar That comment from the OP was added after I closed the question and not part of the original text. If he seeks a delay, why not just use setTimeout and then invoke the reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reset()` is a method on the DOM element, not a jQuery method.

```
document.getElementById(formid).reset();
```

or

```
$('#formid')[0].reset();
```

Comment: Also, your event fire before the submit.

Comment: Thank you, that cleared the form field, but unfortunately it clears before the POST is made... I changed to `onsubmit`, but that does the same thing.

Comment: Other than using AJAX, I don't think there's a way to run your added code after the post.

Comment: `onsubmit` has to be in the `form` element, not the `button`. But then it will still run before the actual submission.